# reading from micro-controller

Tags: c#, serial-port, arduino

I have a Arduino micro-controller . The micro-controller works(i have an app that shows me the the micro-controller 'spits' out data. The thing is that i have implemented some code ( from http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/eclipsed4utoo/serialportcommunication12082008111137am/serialportcommunication.aspx ) :

Here i initialize the SerialPort

```
_serialPort = new SerialPort("COM17", 19200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
_serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
_serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(sp_DataReceived);
_serialPort.ReadTimeout = 1000;
_serialPort.WriteTimeout = 1000;
_serialPort.Open();
```

And here i have the listening handler :

```
void sp_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    string data = _serialPort.ReadLine();
    this.BeginInvoke(new SetTextDeleg(si_DataReceived), new object[] { data });
}
```

But i get this error :`The operation has timed out.` at `string data = _serialPort.ReadLine();` in the handler .

The COM port is COM17 and the port opens ( a led on the micro-controller shows it ). Any idea why the operation timed out ?

i.e. The program loaded into the micro-controller is set to 'shoot' data at 1 second.

Comment: Is there a reason behind the thread.sleep? Won't the function get invoked only once data is ready to be received?

Comment: if i comment the thread.sleep, the program just stops faster. (i.e. 1 second faster )

Comment: did you try those COM settings into HyperTerminal (or whatever com port console you have) ? did you try a longer timeout, like 30 seconds for a start ?

Comment: the arduino micro-controller comes with a display console and it works  okay. I've tried a longer timeout put the same problem occurs .

Comment: I found a better program that works : http://csharp.simpleserial.com/ for anyone interested !!!!

Answer (score 2):

The source of the problem is likely on the other end of the wire.  To let SerialPort.ReadLine() complete and not generate a time-out error you must transmit a line end character sequence.  The value of SerialPort.NewLine, which defaults to the line feed control character ("\n").  If you transmit bytes instead of characters then you should use Read() instead.

You should also implement the ErrorReceived event so you can detect communication errors.  The kind you'll get when the communication parameters do not match, like Baudrate, Parity, Databits and Stopbits.

Comment: @Badescu: In case it's not clear in Hans' response, ReadLine won't return until it reads an end of line character, or times out. It sounds like your device is not sending the EOL.

Comment: @Hans sorry about commenting an old answer but I'm having a [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18789887/2208810) with serial communication and I searched a lot of similar questions and I didn't find any answer yet, can you give me some help?

Answer (score 1):

You can't assume that when the DataRcvd event handler fires that you have everything that was sent by the other end.  You likely are receiving pieces i.e. the micro controller sends ABCDEFGHI(newlinechar) and the event handler fires with ABC in the buffer.

I agree that if the micro controller is not sending newline then it will never work.

Answer (score 0):

If the Arduino in question is a Leandro, Micro, or other Atmega32u4 based board, you'll need to set RTS and DTR high, otherwise you'll not receive any data.

```
_port.Handshake = Handshake.None;
_port.Open();
_port.RtsEnable = true;
_port.DtrEnable = true;
```