# Not sending Serial data in C# application

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port, arduino, .net-4.5

I have two Arduinos that allow  messages exchange via Serial Port using Serial Monitor.

If I use Serial Monitor in both sides everything works fine. If I use my C# application nothing happens. I tried to send from Serial Monitor for C# App and it works but not the reverse.

```
// ...
comPort1.Open();
// ...
private void comPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Invoke(new EventHandler(processData));
}
private void processData(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string inData = comPort1.ReadExisting();
    msgBoxLog.AppendText(inData);
}
// ...
private void sendButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string my_str = "my string";
    msgBoxLog.AppendText(msgBox.Text + my_str);
    comPort1.Write(msgBox.Text);
}
```

*RtsEnable* and *DtrEnable* are both Enabled

Comment: I've had bad luck using the DataReceived event in the built-in serial port libraries.  It seems to be buggy and miss data fairly frequently.  I've always had to resort to either using a polling approach (using a Timer or a tight while loop in a separate thread), or 3rd party libraries.

Comment: Why you are using an EventHandler? why you are not directly write string inData = comPort1.ReadExisting();
    msgBoxLog.AppendText(inData);  Inside comPort1_DataReceived()

Comment: @MehrdadKamelzadeh This will not work. I need to Make Thread-Safe Calls to Windows Forms Controls or I will get an `InvalidOperationException`

Comment: @mafap put a breakpoint there to see if it fires or not when new data is coming I mean inside comPort1_DataReceived()

Comment: @MehrdadKamelzadeh I tried that but didn't find what's wrong. The problem is when I send from my application. When I send from SerialMonitor to my application it works, so it is receiving

Comment: Are you using  `string my_str = "my string";
    msgBoxLog.AppendText(my_str);
    comPort1.Write(my_str);` to send data? if yes try using `comPort1.Writeline("my string")` instead and check if it works.

Comment: @MehrdadKamelzadeh yes, it sends the string to my editBox (msgBoxLog) and to Serial Port. I tried before and didn't work :/

Comment: When I send something in SerialMonitor, Arduino receives and sends the data. When I send from my application, Arduino just receives the data.

Comment: I tried all [this solutions](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=serial%20data%20send%20c%23&emptyWatermark=true&ac=5) and can't get this working :@

Comment: @DaxFohl can you tell me what kind of solutions did you use?

Comment: Reading your question a bit more carefully, it looks like you've had trouble with the C# Send, but the C# Receive is working fine.  Is that correct?  I've never had problems with the Send functionality before, so I'm not sure I can be much help.

Comment: (Just as a sanity check, the `sendButton_Click` *is* getting called when you click the button, right?  You're seeing it append on the msgBoxLog?)

Comment: @DaxFohl That's correct and yes, `sendButton_Click` is getting called. `my_str` is appended but not sent to serial port (Arduino lights de Rx LED but not the Tx).

Comment: Why would you expect the Tx LED to light up if it's just receiving something from the PC?  What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: @DaxFohl The usual process when I use SerialMonitor is: PC (COM1) > Arduino > Arduino receives (Rx ligh up) > Arduino send (Tx) > PC (COM2). And this is not happening with my application.

Comment: Okay, sounds like something Arduino-specific, like it's expecting some of the Enable pins to be set/unset before sending a response.  I haven't messed with Arduino or needed to manage any of these pins before in my applications, so I'm not sure I can help.  It sounds like you're transmitting the data from C# to the Arduino just fine though; the issue is figuring out what you have to do to allow the Arduino to respond.  Read the documentation thoroughly and it should be in there somewhere.

Comment: @DaxFohl I don't know because using the Serial Monitor [from Arduino IDE] everything works fine :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, with `Console.Write(msgBox.Text);` I realized it was just a silly problem, I was not sending *msgBox.Text* as I wanted. It should be:

```
private void sendButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string my_str = "my string";
    comPort1.Write(msgBox.Text); //Console.Write(msgBox.Text);
    msgBoxLog.AppendText(msgBox.Text + my_str);
}
```