# Send special characters to Serial Port

Tags: c#, winforms, encoding, serial-port

I have an application that allow exchange messages and I'm trying to send a string with special characters

```
string my_str = "isto não está a funcionar! (pt)";
comPort1.Write(my_str);
```

But I receive `isto n?o est? a funcionar! (pt)` .

I tried to put `comPort1.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;` before but it's not working yet. I tried diferent encodings.

Comment: How and where do you receive the mentioned output? Is the encoding set correctly there?

Comment: You need to put that encoding on both the sender and the receiver. If the receiver is reading bytes and converting to a string, you need to use `Encoding.Utf8.GetString` rather than `Encoding.ASCII.GetString`.

Comment: @x29a I created an application to exchange messages. This output is with the default encoding (ASCII?). If I use `comPort1.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;` I get the same thing but `?` is other character

Comment: @JimMischel in the receiver I'm using `comPort1.ReadExisting();`

Comment: We don't have enough information to give you a good answer. You need to show us your send and receive code.

Comment: @JimMischel My send and receive code is available [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18789887/2208810). Just changes the data that is being sent.

Comment: The default encoding for the .NET `SerialPort` is `Encoding.ASCII`. That's definitely going to give you a `?` with characters above 127. I don't know what the Arduino's default is: perhaps UTF8, or perhaps something like ISO-8859-2 (i.e. Latin-1). I would suggest changing the encoding to an 8-bit encoding like Windows-1252 or Latin-1. Or better yet, figure out what the Arduino is expecting, and use that.

Comment: @JimMischel In Arduino forum talks about [ASCII](http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/Print) text but if I use Serial Monitor [from Arduino IDE] all the characters are shown correctly. I tried to set Encoding and Decoding but with no sucess, can you show me an example according to my previous code?

Comment: Got this working with `mySerialPort.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);`

Answer (score 4):

If you write the encoded bytes of your string to the port, they will be sent correctly.
This piece of code will do the trick for you:

```
string my_str = "isto não está a funcionar! (pt)";
byte[] my_bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
comPort1.Write(my_bytes, 0, my_bytes.Length);
```

Comment: Thanks but I have this working now like I said in my last comment :)