# SerialPort receive ?? chars, encoding is not right

Tags: c#, serial-port, xbee

In the documentation for SerialPort.Write in MS, says :
 By default, SerialPort uses ASCIIEncoding to encode the characters. ASCIIEncoding encodes all characters greater than 127 as (char)63 or '?'. To support additional characters in that range, set Encoding to UTF8Encoding, UTF32Encoding, or UnicodeEncoding.

Can anyone know how i set the Encoding of my serialport to one of that options??

Comment: You found SerialPort.Write method and documentation and didn't looked at all properties of SerialPort class?? Also in what you posted is already the answer - read it againt! Hint: SET ENCODING TO...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18986941/891715

Comment: i wanted to know how, i know that the types of encoding are there. you dont understand my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.Encoding Property?

Like this:

```
Encoding enc = new UTF8Encoding(true, true);
YourPort.Encoding = enc;
```

Comment: Almost, i do this:
serialPort1.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252");

Comment: @RuiOliveira Also if I were you I would not trust W1252. It is the technology of the last century and there is no garantee that your clients will only use characters that fit in. UTF-8 can handle every unicode character.

Comment: thanks for helping, i try with 
serialPort1.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8; and it works to, and i prefer :)

Comment: @mg30rg and an ancient device connected through _serial port_ is supposed to support UTF-8? It all depends on the device, consult the manual for the encoding to use.

Comment: @CodeCaster Ancient devices will not support W1252 either. It will work with ASCII256, which is not natively supported.

Comment: You cannot say what encoding a non-specified device will use, hence my remark _"consult the manual for the encoding to use"_.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the text you included in your question:

> To support additional characters in that range, set [`Encoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx) to [`UTF8Encoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.utf8encoding(v=vs.110).aspx), UTF32Encoding, or UnicodeEncoding.

You most likely want to find out and apply the proper encoding, like Windows-1252 as [demonstrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714533/how-to-apply-encoding-when-reading-from-a-serial-port).