# sending/receiving data in Serial Port

Tags: c#, serial-port, arduino

I have some code that allows me to receive and send data via Serial Port with Arduino

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(1200);
  Serial1.begin(1200);
}

void loop() {
  // Send data
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    char inChar = Serial.read();
    //...
  }
  else {
    Serial1.println(0xAA); // need to transmit always
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH); delay(5);
    digitalWrite(13, LOW); delay(5);
  }

  // Receive data
  if (Serial1.available() > 0) {
    char inChar = Serial1.read();
    //...
  }
}
```

I need this line `Serial1.println(0xAA);` because I have a circuit that needs always something being transmitted in order to work (noise issues). If I don't have the `else` statment it works good but I need to have Serial Port always transmiting something too.

The problem is with my C# application ([my send/receive code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18789887/2208810) in C#), where I type the messages to send, I can't send any data. I think it is because buffer is always full. I read something about double buffering and threading but I don't know how can it make this work nor wich side I need to change (arduino or c#). Any ideias?

NOTE: everithing works fine without the *else* statment. Now I need some way to make  the other code work with it.

Comment: Are you saying that your user interface locks up and you can't enter any data? Does writing to `SerialPort1` affect the device that's connected to `SerialPort`? You don't say if this `loop` is executing on the UI thread or on a separate thread. There isn't enough information here to even guess at what the problem is.

Comment: @JimMischel I can enter data but I'm not receiving the data I send. I have 2 Arduinos communicating and when I write to `SerialPort1` (PC -> Arduino) the other Arduino can receive that data. In my application, in the receiver, there is an event that creates another thread.

Comment: I still don't understand. Your `loop` method has a comment that says "send data", but then it tries to read from `Serial`. I don't see any code that sends to `Serial`. The send/receive code in the other question just adds to the confusion because I don't know if `comPort1` in that code corresponds to one of the ports you describe in this question. You simply haven't provided enough information. Give us a *complete* and *understandable* example that illustrates the problem. In particular, explain how you have these things hooked up. A diagram might be helpful.

Comment: have tried `Serial.write(0xAA)` ?

Comment: @JimMischel I'm using [Arduino Leonardo](http://arduino.cc/en/reference/serial), this board uses Serial1 to communicate via TTL (5V) serial on pins 0 (RX) and 1 (TX). Serial is reserved for USB CDC communication. Anyway I said this is working, I'm just worried with `Serial1.println(0xAA);` or some way to do that. `comPort1` corresponds to `SerialPort1` in Arduino. The boards are connected like in [this image](https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQbbyAed4MDgfFnwvtrWb_qOkAqJt_xaWHYvbpesD8ATKscVYrWwg). Something like TX1->RX2 TX2->RX3 TX3->RX4 and so on